# Remote debugging doesn't work properly

Tags: visual-studio-2010, debugging, remote-debugging

In Visual Studio 2010, I'm using Remote Debugger to debug my program. It's weird that F10 works and steps over code lines, but no breakpoint is hit. Running the program by F5 causes the program to run neglecting all breakpoints.
why?

Comment: Wrong symbols on the remote machine?

Comment: of what kind? apparently not.

Comment: If F10 works but it doesn't hit breakpoints you set there's a chance some of the files you are hitting breakpoints in don't correspond to the debug symbols. Try rebuilding and redeploying. Also have a way to check the version you are attached to.

Comment: a breakpoint on the same line which is hit by F10 is not hit!